# VAL language and velocity control of industrial robot

Tags: control, manipulator

In my bachelor, I programmed CNC machines. Now, working with an Industrial robot arm, I learn that their programming languages are mostly similar. VAL is a typical example, for instance:

```
PROGRAM PICKPLACE
  1. MOVE P1
  2. MOVE P2
  3. MOVE P3
  4. CLOSEI 0.00
  5. MOVE P4
  6. MOVE P5
  7. OPENI 0.00
  8. MOVE P1
.END
```

Most of the cases, control of a robot arm is similar to this example. Cleary, move end-effector to a point with a given pose.

But... is there any way that I can control the end-effector (EE) speed? An example is "Move EE to P1 with time duration T1", or "Move EE to P1 with velocity V1" (I could have only seen defining for joint rotational velocity) In other way of speaking, I can command the EE to move from P0 to P1 but cannot control the duration of that traverse which is necessary in cases of EE velocity control

This is the programming manual for my robot mediafire.com/?agl76pi7t7v4hjv. The velocity control I'm talking about is not joint velocity but end-effector velocity. But EE_screw = robot_Jacobian*joint_vel which means to control EE velocity, it resolves in control joint velocity. About the inverse kinematic, I've already programmed a module to solve the robot

the experienced in robotics programming and VAL please help! I've stuck in this problem for months